# how does Ethereum accounts works with regards to balance of Ethereum and ERC20 tokens

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, bitcoin, ether

I know that for Bitcoin, each address get its BTC balance from its history of transactions. What about for ethereum? How do we know the **ETH balance** and **ERC20 token balance(s)** of an Eth address?

Thank you very much

1. For each ethereum address, do we get its ETH balance from the ethereum **world state**'s database?
2. how do we know an ethereum account's balances of each ERC20 token - is there a data field for each address containing all the erc20 contracts an account has interacted with, then the wallet checks the smart contract's **balanceOf** field? If not, how do we know what erc20 tokens are found in an eth wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ERC-20 token balance of each address is stored in the storage slot of a smart contract

The smart contract itself has an address. So you need to query `address of a smart contract` -> `its storage slot`.

You *cannot* query what tokens any address has because of the broken design of ERC-20 ([here more about the issue](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1462724587905503236)). Only way to know this is to build a full world indexer for Ethereum blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

actually it is not the case.
as the yellowpaper of ethereum define it, the balance is stored the same way the storage, the code,  and the nonce are stored : in the world state.

"The account state, σ[a], comprises the following four
fields:

**nonce:** A scalar value equal to the number of transactions sent from this address or, in the case
of accounts with associated code, the number of
contract-creations made by this account. For account of address a in state σ, this would be formally denoted σ[a]n.

**balance:** A scalar value equal to the number of Wei
owned by this address. Formally denoted σ[a]b.

**storageRoot:** A 256-bit hash of the root node of a
Merkle Patricia tree that encodes the storage contents of the account (a mapping between 256-bit
integer values), encoded into the trie as a mapping
from the Keccak 256-bit hash of the 256-bit integer
keys to the RLP-encoded 256-bit integer values.
The hash is formally denoted σ[a]s.

**codeHash:** The hash of the EVM code of this
account—this is the code that gets executed should"

[yellowpaper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)